# How can i return the value retrieved from retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, return, retrofit

I want to return the value that returns from a retrofit API enqueue call. My function returns null as the enqueue is asynchronous and it executes after my function has returned null.

```
fun login(context: Context, username: String, password: String): UserModel {
    var userModel = UserModel()

    RetrofitClient.AUTH = Prefs.getInstance(context).auth
    Log.e("TAG", "Login Auth: " + RetrofitClient.AUTH)
    RetrofitClient.instance.userLogin(username, password)
        .enqueue(object : Callback<LoginModel> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginModel>, response: Response<LoginModel>) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Login Response: " + response.message())
                Log.e("TAG", "Login Response: " + response.body().toString())
                userModel = response!!.body()!!.data.user
                Log.e("TAG", "Login User Model Mutable Live Data: " + userModel.full_name)
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginModel>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(context, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        })

    Log.e("TAG", "Return Login: " + userModel.full_name)
    return userModel
}
```

The log inside the enqueue function returns the accurate value that i need. But the log above return returns null.

Comment: You can use live data / coroutines / interface callback  to achieve this.

Comment: You can accept lambda as parameter to the funciton and invoke it inside onResponse() or use coroutine to return from the function asynchronously example: [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/suspend-coroutine.html).

Comment: I have tried using live data but it was of no use as this function is inside my repository and i'm trying to call it from my ViewModel.

Comment: How can i use Interface callback with it?

Answer (score 1):

Make an interface .Something like this:

```
interface ApiResult{
 void success(UserModel userModel);
 void error(Throwable t);
}
```

Then pass an instance of this interface as a parameter to your login method:

```
fun login(context: Context, username: String, password: String,result : ApiResult) {
    var userModel = UserModel()
    RetrofitClient.AUTH = Prefs.getInstance(context).auth
    Log.e("TAG", "Login Auth: " + RetrofitClient.AUTH)
    RetrofitClient.instance.userLogin(username, password)
        .enqueue(object : Callback<LoginModel> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginModel>, response: Response<LoginModel>) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Login Response: " + response.message())
                Log.e("TAG", "Login Response: " + response.body().toString())
                userModel = response!!.body()!!.data.user
                Log.e("TAG", "Login User Model Mutable Live Data: " + userModel.full_name)
                result.success(userModel);
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginModel>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(context, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                result.error(t);
            }
        })
}
```

This is a simple example of using callbacks to get API result. You can also use lambda methods instead of callbacks